Get the KeyCloak user's first and last name with Spring AuditorAware with Spring Cloud microservice
I am currently setting up a microservice architecture with Spring Cloud 2023.x. The microservices I have are a KeyCloak server, gateway server, config server, Eureka server, and a plant-ms service.
I would like to implement Auditing using Spring's AuditorAware, but the issue is that I am not sure whether I should implement it in the gateway server or in the plant-ms service.
In the Auditing, I would like to retrieve the user's first and last name from the KeyCloak service and insert them into an entry in the plant-ms service. (i found many outdated examples).
// plante-ms/../application.yml
spring:
  config:
    import: "optional:configserver:http://localhost:8080/"
eureka:
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8070/eureka/

// gatewayserver/../application.yml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: "http://localhost:8090/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/certs"

Right now my question is, where i have to put this code (gatewayserver, eurekaserver, configserver or each microservices like plante-ms/payment-ms)
@Component
public class AuditorAware implements org.springframework.data.domain.AuditorAware<String> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuditorAware.class);


    @Override
    public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor() {

    // ….
    }
}

Thanks

What is this "plant-ms service" and how is it configured (security config, application properties and dependencies)?

Resolved: missing entry into plant-ms. Team, you can closed. Thanks.
